# 3ds purchases not in history after system transfer

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

When I go to re downloadable software there’s nothing there, all my purchases are gone! And after the system transfer my old system was wiped clean and the games are not available to redownload on the old one either someone please help..